# Delete a single entry in many to one relationship Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
public class User {

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long userId;

    String name;    

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<>();
}   

public class Player {

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long playerId;

    String team; 

    @ManyToOne
    User user;
}
```

User can have multiple players. 
I want to delete a single player i.e. reference from player table[1 entry], user_player[1 entry] table .

Please help, how can i do it without using HQL.

```
User u = new User(); 
u.name = "George"; 
Player p1 = new Player(); 
p1.team = "india"; 
Player p2 = new Player(); 
p2.team = "us"; 
session.beginTransaction(); 
session.save(u); 
session.save(p1); 
session.save(p2); 
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

now i want to delete p1, but if i use session.delete then one reference in user_player table is left. I don't want to delete the whole user. Thanks for response

Comment: How is the single player selected ? Are you using an EntityManager ?

Comment: User u=new User();
u.name="George";
Player p1=new Player();
p1.team="india";
Player p2=new Player();
p2.team="us";
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(u);
session.save(p1);
session.save(p2);
session.getTransaction().commit();

now i want to delete p1, but if i use session.delete then one reference in user_player table is left. I don't want to delete the whole user.
Thanks for response

Comment: If I understand things correctly, you're deleting a User ? It will delete all dependant Players because of `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE`. http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Cascading_Remove_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your cascade to `cascade-all` this all becomes simpler. You have an aggregate object, and you should only perform database operations on the aggregate root, which in your case is `User`. So, you should add and remove players from `User`, and save only that. The save will then cascade to the players. If you remove the player from the user, then save the user, the player will be deleted by hibernate for you. To make this work, you have to have an `addPlayer(Player player)` method in your `User` class which adds the player to the collection, and a `setUser(User user)` method on your `Player` class, which is called from within `addPlayer()`.